# authorization header is too large from JWT token roles and asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, header, jwt, request-headers, authorization-header

I add all user roles to the role claim of JWT and when added more roles I get this error
http://localhost:4200 has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
and when removing some of the roles everything working fine

Answer (score 0):

By default, a user's claims are stored in the **authentication cookie**. If the authentication cookie is too large, it can cause the app to fail because:

- The browser detects that the cookie header is too long.
- The overall **size of the request** is too large.

If a large amount of user data is required for processing user requests:

1. Limit the number and size of user claims for request processing to
   only what the app requires.
2. Use a custom **ITicketStore** for the Cookie Authentication
   Middleware's SessionStore to store identity across requests.
   Preserve large quantities of identity information on the server
   while only sending a small session identifier key to the client.

And maybe this answer would help you     [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562660/recommended-best-practice-for-role-claims-as-permissions)