# Blazor Authentication via existing database table

Tags: blazor-server-side

I want to build a Blazor server application that has user authentication. The only experience I have with Blazor was a simple app for work that used AD authentication and made various api calls to get the data necessary.

I have an existing sql table containing: userId, username, permissionLevel

Basically I want to be able to make a new table with the username and a hashed password that when matched will return an object containing userid, username, and permissionlevel that will be used for authentication in the Blazor server app.

Is this possible and are there any resources pointing me in the right direction for this? I have searched but have not come up with anything I am looking for. I am looking for examples of how to display certain options based on PermissionLevel.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor Server supports Policy based authorization (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorize-attribute) - Example:

```
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "PermissionLevel.5")]

<p>You can only see this if you satisfy the 'PermissionLevel.5' policy.</p>
```

You can register all policies (PermissionLevels) in Startup.cs, example:

```
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("PermissionLevel.5",
                    policy => policy.RequireClaim("Permission", "PermissionLevel.5"));
            });
```

Unlike with Role based authorization, only a single policy can be applied inside any `Authorize` attribute, or `AuthorizeView` component.  You can however evaluate multiple requirements for a single policy (such as if PermissionLevel must be '5' or higher) by customising your own AuthorizationHandler (see MS Docs for some good examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-a-handler-for-multiple-requirements - You can also refer to my last link below for a detailed example using Role Claims, by @pacificoder).

If you use ASP.NET Identity (such as with a Blazor Project's Individual User Accounts), the **AspNetUserClaims** table is created for you (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0#entity-types), which contains all the user-claim pairs.  Claims can be assigned to users during runtime by using `UserManager.AddClaimAsync()`.

This would be sufficient if you do not have many claims - However the more permissions and roles a user has, the larger the access token becomes (and you could get an "Access token must not be longer than 4K" error - I started getting this after adding 5+ claims to a role, but not sure how easy it is to exceed 4K with user claims only...).

If you consider using Policy-based authorization, I would recommend taking a look at this answer by @pacificoder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49539930/13678817 - Although this relates to Role based policies, the same approach can be used for user based policies, and I also liked the way Enums are used to create and add all the permissions/policies.